# Power series radius of convergence question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

Find the radius of convergence of the following series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(x-1)^{2n}}{n9^n} $

What I did was:

I used the ratio test and got $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty }|\frac {(x-1)^{2n+2}}{(n+1)9^{n+1}}\cdot \frac {n9^{n}}{(x-1)^{2n}} |$ I can remove the absolute value since all $n$ is positive and $(x-1)^2$ is positive, $(x-1)^2$ $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty } \frac {n}{9n+9}$ and lastly I got that the $limit$ is $\frac {1}{9}$ so the radius is $9$

then I checked what happens in the series when I put $-9$ and $9$
And I got that it diverges on both of them so my answer is $(-9,9)$ but according to online calculators it is not right.. what did I miss or do wrong?
thanks for any help and tips!

Comment: It is $(x-1)^{\color{red}2}$ which has to be  $\le 9$, so the radius of convergence is $3$.

Comment: From the ratio test you can conclude that $(x-1)^2 < 9$, not that $ |x|<9$. Calculating the root we get $|x-1|<3$ or $-2<x<4$. Then you have to check for convergence at $-2$ and $4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the limit is $\frac{(x-1)^2}9$. So, the series converges absolutely if $\frac{(x-1)^2}9<1(\iff|x-1|<3)$ and diverges if $\frac{(x-1)^2}9>1(\iff|x-1|>3)$. So, the radius of convergence is $3$.

Comment: thank you for the quick answer but why can't I remove the absolute value from $(x+1)^2$?

Comment: Well, you can, since $(x-1)^2\geqslant0$. But it turns out that$$\frac{(x-1)^2}9<1\iff\sqrt{\frac{(x-1)^2}9}<1\iff\frac{|x-1|}3<1$$

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with Cauchy-Hadamard Theorem. First, observe that we have the power series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x-1)^{2n}}{n\,9^n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-1)^n$$

with

$$a_n=\begin{cases}0\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;,&n\;\text{is odd}\\{}\\
\cfrac1{\frac n2\,9^{n/2}}\;,&n\;\text{ is even}\end{cases}$$

Thus, by the CHT, we get that

$$\frac1R=\limsup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt[n]\frac n2\,9^{1/2}}=\frac1{\sqrt9}=\frac13\implies R=3$$